# Switching between different numeric formatting styles in an iostream

Tags: c++, iostream, number-formatting, scientific-notation

I have a C++ program writing output to an `iostream`, however I need to switch often between different numeric styles, e.g. between scientific and non-scientific. Here is what I'm looking at:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << setw(2) << 1 << ' ' << setw(4) << 0.25 << ' ';
    cout.width(6);
    cout.setf(ios::scientific, ios::floatfield);
    cout << 3.0 << ' ';
    cout.unsetf(ios::floatfield);
    cout << 4.0 << ' ';
    cout.setf(ios::scientific, ios::floatfield);
    cout << 3.0 << ' ';
    cout.unsetf(ios::floatfield);
    cout << 4.0 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Is this ridiculousness required? It looks terrible. As a comparison, this looks much more sane in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%2d %4g %6e %6g %6e %6g\n", 1, 0.25, 3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 4.0);
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to use `iostream` in C++ to make it easier to read?

Answer (score 3):

This may also be overkill but you could implement some light weight types that did the custom formatting for you

```
struct Scientific
{
  double value;
  Scientific(double value) : value(value) { } 
};

ostream& operator<< (ostream &o, const Scientific& p) {
  o.setf(ios::scientific, ios::floatfield);
  o << p.value;
  o.unsetf(ios::floatfield);
  return o;
}
```

Then the scientific notation could be specified as an annotation to the value instead of multiple lines

```
cout << 1 << ' ' << Scientific(2.0) << ' ' << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be by using macros:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using std::hex;
using std::scientific;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

define H hex
define S scientific

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  cout << H << 10 << S << 10 << endl;

  return 0;
}
```